# @WebService Annotation not working on Weblogic 10.3

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, weblogic-10.x

I have the class below embedded in an EAR file i have deployed to Weblogic 10.3.

I thought that it was all i needed in order to have the Web Service become available for use.

In the console - when i expand the EAR i see

`WebServices -> 
None to display`

- The EAR is deployed and active.
- WebServiceMain is definitely packaged in the EAR

I know there are JWSC tasks i can add to the ANT Script - but i thought it was as simple as this?

```java
package messagecenter.ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

/**
 * @author KwikkSilva
 */
@WebService
public class WebServiceMain {

    @WebMethod
    public String getHello()
    {
    return "hello!!!!!";
    }
}
```

Comment: is simple as this in jee6 but you are working in 10.3 which is jee5 so try the below answer

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial :
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webserv/setenv.html#IterativeDevelopment

However if your deployment package is an ear you need to have an application.xml where you will specify that you have a war or jar as module inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
   <display-name>cccc</display-name>
   <description>some ws</description>
   <module>
      <web>
         <web-uri>webservice.war</web-uri>
         <context-root>client</context-root>
      </web>
   </module> 
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Cris - i think this might be the way to go. I thought i did not have to get into it at that level - and just annotate and pack it in a JAR then an EAR but it might need the WAR like you said.

Answer (score 0):

please @Stateless ,although i didnt find anywhere in documentation but by adding @Stateless it recognizes and creates webservice  so your code will look like this

```
package messagecenter.ws;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

/**
 * @author KwikkSilva
 */
@Stateless
@WebService
public class WebServiceMain {

    @WebMethod
    public String getHello()
    {
    return "hello!!!!!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
After doing a lot of research, the solution was to specify in weblogic-application.xml, in the prefer-application-packages tag the following:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.*</package-name>
    <package-name>weblogic.wsee.saaj.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

Additionally, I imported the saaj-impl-1.3.1.8.jar in my project. 
This did the trick, and the reason for this, appears to be that, to perform certain SOAP operations, weblogic seems to prefer certain default libraries that are not recognizing properly the @WebService annotation.